# How to submit a (documentation) ticket

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are encouraged to submit a ticket for bugs. However, http://www.ros.org/wiki/Tickets:

1. Does not include an entry for documentation 'bugs'
2. All three topic areas listed on that page lead to lists of 'handoff' requests, rather than bug entry forms.

Which link am I missing?

thanks,

Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10861/how-to-submit-a-(documentation)-ticket/) by [paepcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/952/paepcke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-08-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Filing a ticket for documentation bugs is no different than filing a ticket for a software bug.  You simply file a ticket for the software that the defect is related to.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you would like to file a bug report go to the package page scroll to the bottom and click on the report bugs link. Many package pages in ROS have report bugs links.

If the link does not exist look at the package url and determine which repository the package is located in. Then go to the main repository TRAC page and login. Once you are logged in you will see in the right top hand corner there is now a link for New Ticket. Click on the New Ticket link to file a ticket.

Remember when filing a ticket it is important to provide as much information as possible for recreating the bug. Typically you will want to provide command you ran to cause the error, which version of ROS, OS, and any other system information that might be relevant.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3